# OData Expand fails on Client Win8.1 universal app

Tags: c#, odata, win-universal-app

Just a quick question, is this not supported in a Win 8.1 universal class library? Or if it is, can anyone help with what i'm doing wrong.

```
http://jbsapplication.azurewebsites.net/Modules?$filter=Name%20eq%20'JBS%20Electronic%20forms'&$expand=Menus
```

When I do this from the browser or Fiddler I receive the correct response.

My code in the client view model class is as follows (using the OData Client v2 code generated objects)

```
var application = new UriBuilder(ServiceBaseAddress);
var context = new Models.Application(application.Uri);

var modulesQuery = context.Modules.Expand(m=>m.Menus).Where(m => m.Name == ApplicationName);
var modules = await ((DataServiceQuery<Module>) modulesQuery).ExecuteAsync();
_currentModule = modules.FirstOrDefault();
```

The following exception is generated on the last line

A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException' occurred in Microsoft.OData.Core.DLL

Additional information: When writing a JSON response, a user model must be specified and the entity set and entity type must be passed to the ODataMessageWriter.CreateODataEntryWriter method or the ODataFeedAndEntrySerializationInfo must be set on the ODataEntry or ODataFeed that is being writen.

If I remove the Expand portion of the request, everything is fine, but I need to then perform another round trip to get the menus.

A cut down reference for the Module class:

```
[Key("Id")]
public class Module: BindableBase
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }

    DataServiceCollection<Menu> _menus = new DataServiceCollection<Menu>(null,TrackingMode.AutoChangeTracking);

    public DataServiceCollection<Menu> Menus
    {
        get { return _menus; }
        set
        {
            _menus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Menus");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have encountered the problem you describe when I forgot to add the expanding entity into the ODataModelBuilder as an EntitySet. Try this in your ASP.NET OData Web API:

```
builder.EntitySet<Menus>("Menus");
```

Comment: I found that the JavaScript client could expand the query fine without the expanding entity in the ODataModelBuilder; the .NET client on the other hand required the expanding entity to be added to the ODataModelBuilder.

Comment: @Bvrce guess that makes sense - i.e. differences in strong vs weak typing in JS vs c# .net

Answer (score 0):

Models with an ID property need to be explicitly expanded by clients, and expandable models need to be registered as entitysets with the builder for the auto-generated OData client to be able to call expand.